# Android Listview ArrayAdapter example

Tags: android, listview, divider

I am using custom row view in `ListView` widget.

I am having `getView` method in my implementation.

What I want is that I want to hide divider image of 2nd row how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the image that displays when you call setDivider, or android:divider in XML, I don't think you can hide it on some rows and show it on other rows.

Instead, you can create a PNG (probably with draw9patch) with a border on the top or the bottom, and in your ListAdapter.getView() set it as the background on whatever rows you want.  On the other rows, you can set a background that has no border.  This will give the appearance that some rows have a divider, and others don't.